# SOAP, HTTP(S) POST. XML and Schema mess

Tags: http, soap, xsd, schema

I am very confused. I have a xsd file, no wsdl and apparently i send this data through SOAP. Now looking at all i went back and notice this

> (using ssl) The regular session begins
>   with a HTTP POST request sent by the
>   client. The body of the request
>   contains XML document compliant with
>   SOME_API Request schema

So... i am not using SOAP at all? Am i suppose to do something with the schema file they provide me? No one here (at work) seems to know.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading [Http made really easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/). Soap uses http to send its messages from client to server, and when the document you are talking about is asking you to send a message to the soap server using the HTTP protocol. A bit of googling should find you some nice soap getting started guides.

The message you send is an XML document that uses this schema. The schema defines the types of XML that are valid. Get a good XML editor such as [oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) and tell it you are making a new xml document using a schema (point to your xsd file) and see what you are allowed to type.

My search turned up these two:

- [Tutorial point SOAP Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/)
- [W3Cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/default.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Just send an HTTP POST with XML that complies to the schema. You can either read the schema manually (which can be hard), or use an XML editor like Tom is suggesting, but there's another possibility: Many platforms offer tools that automatically generate classes from XSD schema, which you can later automatically serialize to get the correct XML.

For example, if you use .NET: Use the xsd.exe tool to generate classes from schema, then just fill these with information as regular classes, then use the XmlSerializer to convert the root class to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems that it's not really a SOAP API at all, but rather something like XML-RPC.

Just send an HTTP POST with XML that complies to the schema. You can either read the schema manually (which can be hard), or use an XML editor like Tom is suggesting, but there's another possibility: Many platforms offer tools that automatically generate classes from XSD schema, which you can later automatically serialize to get the correct XML.

For example, if you use .NET: Use the xsd.exe tool to generate classes from schema, then just fill these with information as regular classes, then use the XmlSerializer to convert the root class to XML.

Answer (score 0):

You are learning why standards should be followed.

If this is really a SOAP-based web service, then there must be a WSDL. There is no exception to that. The WSDL is meant to describe everything you need to know about the web service. I strongly suggest you ask the developers of the web service whether it is a SOAP web service, and ask them to supply a WSDL or to explain why they think they should not do that.